# Cannot vertically center floating elements in table cell

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have form elements that are declared inside a table, who are inherently vertically centered to their table cells.

I have a table cell that has a unordered list and a select box floating left in order to inline them with themselves. It seems that having two of these elements in the same cell will break the vertical centering of my second element (the select box) and force to a the top of the cell (still inline with the unordered list, just no longer vertically centered).

I cannot figure out why this is happening and how to fix the problem. Any ideas?

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/pVpnd/1/.

If you hide the unordered list, the select box will center itself within the table cell as it should, but only when it's the lone element within the cell.

Comment: I don't think that you can have two items in the same cell vertically aligned. Tables aren't really meant to be used for laying out forms, only to really display tabular data afaik.

Comment: Use <div> elements instead of <table> for formatting.

Comment: @ Billy I've been able to maintain the vertical centering by replacing the unordered list with a div and keeping the select box. I think there's some layout issue coming from the unordered list that's breaking the select box.

Comment: @Dmytro, tables are often a more simple solution to layout forms. They offer more inline styling which means less CSS lines to code needlessly (see column widths for example). Not to open the table vs. div debate, but table can/should still be used for static layout content IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following CSS instead of float:

```
select,ul{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pVpnd/6/)**

Comment: Hadn't thought of trying inline-block. Works like a charm. Thanks!